# Signalr using MVC 4

Tags: signalr

I am unable to run the chat application using singalr and  I am facing problem with owin.

The following errors occurred while attempting to load the app:

- `No assembly found containing an OwinStartupAttribute.`
- `No 'Configuration' method was found in class 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Runtime.Startup, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Runtime, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.`
- `To disable OWIN startup discovery, add the appSetting owin:AutomaticAppStartup with a value of "false" in your web.config.
  To specify the OWIN startup Assembly, Class, or Method, add the appSetting owin:AppStartup with the fully qualified startup class or configuration method name in your web.config.`

Comment: You should share your code.

Comment: as @ztirom says, what code do you have? Have you setup your hubs, and also what version of SignalR are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're mixing 1.0 and 2.0 components in your project. See the following tutorial for how to upgrade a 1.0 project to 2.0:

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/upgrading-signalr-1x-projects-to-20

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the Startup.cs in your project? More code please.

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.MapSignalR();
    }
}
```

In addition have you setup any hubs?

```
public class ChatBoxHub : Hub
{
    public ChatBoxHub()
    {
    }
}
```